# Which small external GNSS-receivers are tested with QField?

Tags: gps, qfield, hardware-recommendations, compatibility

I would like to use QField with a small external GNNS-receiver that I can connect to my smartphone or tablet via USB or Bluetooth (e.g. [Trimble R1](https://geospatial.trimble.com/products-and-solutions/trimble-r1), [ppm 10xx](https://ppmgmbh.com/gps-produkte/externer-ppm-10xx-gnss-sensor/), [Leica Zeno FLX 100](https://leica-geosystems.com/en-us/products/gis-collectors/smart-antennas/leica-flx100)). Since they are quite expensive, I want to make sure that the GNSS-receiver is compatible with QField before buying one. In the QField documentation it says that "[QField supports connecting external GNSS antennas via bluetooth](https://qfield.org/docs/fieldwork/gps.html)". In this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h58EzJR7XwI), one of the developers of QField mentions that external receivers from Trimble and Emlid have been succesfully tested with QField. Receivers from other companies (e.g. Leica) seem to have problems connecting with QField (see Questions at 1:01:27min).

Does someone have experience with small external GNSS-receivers and QField or know of a list of successfully tested combinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using [Ardusimple](https://www.ardusimple.com/) with a bluetooth modul together with NTRIP client (Lefebure) on Android tablets and this works like a charm. We get RTK accuracy up to 2 cm. A very affordable solution, that we can recommand.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the [Geode of Juniper systems](https://junipersys.com/products/geode) for tree inventory in combination with the NTRIP client app and QField (or Input app). It works smoothless.